# how to get back my wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I had installed bitnami in c:\BitNami(the wamp stack is 5.4.24) on   windows xp in my local disk,and installed wordpress in "c:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.24-0\apache2\htdocs\wordpress", I had write some blogs on the wordpress.
several days ago, my xp crashed, I can't enter into it.I copy all  c:\BitNami into usb,and install win7 in the pc.
I installed c:\BitNami(the wamp stack is 5.4.25),and installed a new  wordpress in "c:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.25-0\apache2\htdocs\wordpress"

Now how can I get back my old content in old wordpress?

Comment: Looks like this is more of a file management issue.  This should probably be on another site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your daily backup and restore to the point before you installed.

If you aren't backing up before installing or upgrading, this is your lesson and you should start doing so.  That would protect you when things go bad.